# "omitempty" for all the fields

Tags: json, go, marshalling

Is there a way using which I can force `omitempty` for all the fields in a struct **without** explicitly specifying it against every field?

```
type Item struct {
    Name     string `json:"item,omitempty"`
    Quantity int    `json:"quantity,omitempty"`
    Price    int    `json:"price,omitempty"`
}
```

This is just an *example*, original struct might have **too** many fields.

It seems both *ugly* and *redundant* to specify `omitempty` against every field, if I need it for all the fields. It would have also great if `json.Marshal()` has someway to ignore empty fields while **marshaling**. Can someone suggest best way to achieve this or this is the best way?

Comment: Best way is to specify `,omitempty` for all fields.

Comment: `json.Marshal` takes one parameter: the object to be marshaled. There is no way to specify any configuration beyond that object, where you can specify configuraiton using tags, as you've found.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the [`json.Marshaller`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) interface to make a custom JSON marshalling.

Example:

```
// Your struct
type Item struct {
    Name     string `json:"item"`
    Quantity int    `json:"quantity"`
    Price    int    `json:"price"`
}

func (i Item) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        Name string `json:"name"` // Fields that you need
    }{
        Name: i.Name,
    })
}
```

Then:

```
i := Item{Name: "Apple", Price: 1200}
itemJSON, err := json.Marshal(i)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("%v", err)
}

fmt.Println(string(itemJSON)) // -> {"name":"Apple"}
```

Also you might find [this article about custom marshalling](http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/) useful.

Also if you need different JSON representations of your struct [this article](https://attilaolah.eu/2014/09/10/json-and-struct-composition-in-go/) will be really useful